# AzureDevops: How to publish test results when tests fail?

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, jestjs

I have some unit tests written with `jest`. Obviously, sometimes they fail. I want to publish the result to the build `Test` section. 
The problem is task `PublishTestResults@2` never runs if a previous task fails, hence no data in test section of the build.
In this case, what I get is the message `##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.`.

Here is my `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
- script: npm run test:publish
    displayName: "Run Unit Tests"
- script: npm run build
    displayName: "Build"
- task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: "Publish unit test result"
    inputs:
      testResultsFiles: "unit_test_report.xml"
      testRunTitle: "Unit tests with Jest"
      mergeTestResults: false
      searchFolder: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
      condition: always()
      failTaskOnFailedTests: false
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have indented `condition: always()` one place too far in your YAML, it should sit at the same level as `displayName`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, but it does look like your `condition` line is indented one too far in your yaml, shoudn't it be directly under `displayName`?